# Maven hibernate jar not found (3.5.1-Final)

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, orm

i'm trying to update the hibernate dependecy in my pom, I had the **3.3.2.GA** version and i changed to **3.5.1-Final**. But maven can't find the jars in the repo, so checking the url.

http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/

in the hibernate section.

I can see that there are't any jar, only pom's. But If i check the entity manager section

There are jars and other files, (in fact maven retrived the files).

I know that i can add this to my repository whis this command line

```
 mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.hibernate -DartifactId=hibernate -Dversion=3.5.1-Final -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
```

But i dont know if other dependencies are required.

I must to say that i added the repository in my pom, like this.

```
   <repository>
        <id>JBOSS</id>
        <name>JBoss Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
```

Tank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `hibernate-core` as `artifactId` in your dependency (from the JBoss repository indeed):

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jboss</id>
    <name>JBoss repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss have started synchronising their own repo with Maven central as [posted on the JBoss community blog](http://community.jboss.org/en/build/blog/2011/05/24/rsync-jbossorg-to-maven-central) , therefore `hibernate` artifacts are now available without the need to add the JBoss repository to your `pom.xml` or repository manager.

[Search result for hibernate-core](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.hibernate%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hibernate-core%22):

[image: search result for hibernate-core]